# Are there any template matching / optical flow algorithms for large image displacement?

Tags: image-registration, template-matching

I had some success with feature-based methods for image registration, but these methods are sometimes unsuitable (e.g. images containing repetitive patterns, very low contrast, low texture, no edges/corners).

I am therefore looking for a direct (pixel-based) global alignment alternative.

So far I looked on algorithms like Horn-Schunck, Lucas-Kanade, ECC but all the examples show only images with very small displacement (few pixels at most).

Is there any direct (pixel-based) method for registering images with a displacement of 200 pixels or more (in any direction)?

So far I am using **simple template matching with exhaustive search over possible image shifts** and Normalised Cross-Correlation error metric, which works, but it is extremely slow (basically $O(n^4)$) and does not allow for rotation.

Are there any faster methods allowing large image shifts/rotations?

Answer (score 2):

I personally like [this one](http://cs.brown.edu/~dqsun/pubs/cvpr_2010_flow.pdf). It is nicely designed for occlusions and large displacements.

But, recent trends in deep learning lead to better results in optical flow such as [this](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiGyKKPk-nJAhXovXIKHYeLCasQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvision.in.tum.de%2F_media%2Fspezial%2Fbib%2Fflownet-iccv-15.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEZblXnPFSiSZVYpCmXBdY0Usk6KQ&sig2=6O8iU-xlHTcGqJrP-qgX3w&cad=rja) and [this](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/rg/papers/DeepFlow_iccv2013.pdf).